# Is there Azure Active Directory max users count limitation?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We want to use Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD) with some applications written in different languages.

These applications are intended for use in large companies so we are concerned
is there some limitations to count of users stored in WAAD? Someone told me there is a 150 000 users limit for all directories but I can't find anywhere is it right or wrong. Can someone provide more details about WAAD limitations?

Thank you!

Comment: Anyone? We will be using Azure for the first time, and there will be several projects for the same subscriber so it's vital for me to know if there are any limits and I still can't find the answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current default limit is 50K users.  However, you can call support and ask for the limit to be raised.  This is a request they are used to fielding and it shouldn't require going through any hoops to get them to raise your limit, though having never done it myself I don't know the process.  The limits change from time to time, usually they are increased.  There are no technical reasons that a tenant can not scale significantly beyond 150K users.  Talk to support as they can likely meet your needs.

Comment: The limit has very recently been raised to 300K objects in a directory as long as you verify a domain.  After that you can still call in to support as indicated above.